# Solving integral equation of an exponential sum

Tags: calculus, integration

Given the following integral equation:
$$
\int_0^\infty  {\left( {{a_1}{e^{ - {b_1}x}} + {a_2}{e^{ - {b_2}x}}} \right)g(x)dx}  = 0, \quad \forall x\ge0
$$
where $a_1,\,a_2,\,b_1,\,b_2 > 0$ and $b_1 \ne b_2$. Can I conclude that $g(x)=0, \forall x\ge 0$?

Comment: what about $g(x)$, no conditions on it?

Comment: $g(x)$ is piecewise-continuous.

Comment: Meanwhile i suggest you to accept the answers given to your questions if they provide a solution. You asked $33$ questions and $23$ of them have at least one answer and you accepted only one of them, which seems abnormal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(x)=0$ is **not** the unique solution to this problem. To see this, take $g(x)=\frac{1}{a_1}e^{b_1 x}g^*(x)$. Then your integral will look like this:
$$\int_{0}^\infty g^*(x)\mbox{d}x+k_1\int_{0}^\infty e^{k_2 x}g^*(x)\mbox{d}x\quad\quad(**)$$

Accordingly the question is: if there exists a function $g^*$ whose integral from $0$ to $\infty$ is positive, however $\int_{0}^\infty e^{k_2 x}g^*(x)\mbox{d}x$ is negative. It doesn't matter how much negative it is because we are free to choose $k_1$ to make it as small as we want and as large as we want so that the whole integral will add up to zero. I will give a counterexample $g^*$ which is piecewise continuous but a simple modification can also give a continuous version of it.

$$g^*(x)=\cases{-1\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\,\,\, \mbox{if}\,\,\,\ 0\leq x<r \\(r+1)e^{-(x-r)}\quad \mbox{if}\quad r\leq x<\infty}$$

$$\int_0^\infty g^*(x)=1\quad\forall r$$ and for some $r$ we have $$-\infty<\int_{0}^\infty e^{k_2 x}g^*(x)\mbox{d}x<0$$

since we are free to choose $k_1$ as we want, there exist some $k_1$ such that $(**)$ results in $0$.